# Excel-VBA: buttons and drop-down lists before scraping data on .aspx web pages

Tags: html, vba, excel, web-scraping

I'd like to use VBA to get a table from a webpage, but I cannot access it directly because I need to switch from a tab to another. The problem relies on the .aspx end of the web page (URL doesn't evolve accordingly).

URL: http://www.morningstar.fr/fr/fundquickrank/default.aspx

[Default page after clicking URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5cxD.jpg)

[Moving to "Long Terme" Tab - URL won't change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oid0w.jpg)

I've managed to build the code for exporting the table to an Excel worksheet, but lack the "navigation" part.

Here is the HTML code that regards the button clicking the "Long Terme Tab":

[HTML Code Long Terme Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJFQy.png)

My starting point is here (ProcessHTMLPage does the table scraping):

```
Sub Browse_Morningstar()

Dim XMLPage As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim HTMLDoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument


XMLPage.Open "GET", "http://www.morningstar.fr/fr/fundquickrank/default.aspx", False
XMLPage.send

HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = XMLPage.responseText


ProcessHTMLPage HTMLDoc

End Sub
```

I suppose the request must be updated somehow.
Sorry if I am not being accurate enough, but I'm kind of new at all this.

Thanks a lot guys!

Comment: Did you ever try the answers below?

Answer (score 1):

### **__doPostBack and onclick event:**

When you inspect the HTML associated with selecting Main Content div bar e.g. `Long Terme`, you can see that there is a java script [`__doPostBack` function](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/667531/doPostBack-function) associated with the `onclick` event for the individual bar items.

**Observe the HTML in question:**

[image: __doPostBack]

To quote from my link above:

> The function takes the following two arguments:
>
> eventTarget  - This contains the ID of the control that caused the
>   post back. eventArgument - This contains any additional data
>   associated with the control.
>
> In any ASP.NET page the two hidden fields: __EVENTTARGET and
>   __EVENTARGUMENT are automatically declared. When a page is posted back to the server ASP.NET inspects __EVENTTARGET and __EVENTARGUMENT
>   values and this way it can decide which of the controls caused the
>   page to be posted back and what is the event that has to be handled.

### tldr;

In the "olden" days of `ASP` there often had to be a form to capture user inputs and then further pages created to accept those inputs (`GET` or `POST`), validate, perform actions and the like. With `ASP.NET` you can declare controls on the server which accept the above arguments and post back to the same page after inspecting the values of

The first argument tells you which control was fired and the second argument provides additional information, which in this case determines what tab information is returned.

We can see from the above that `TabAction` is the control and that the number following it corresponds to the tab of interest e.g. 2 for Long Terme (as 0 - indexed).

In VBA we can execute this JS function in a number of ways but I will use:

```
.document.parentWindow.execScript "__doPostBack('EVENTTARGET', 'EVENTARGUMENT')"
```

This becomes:

```
.document.parentWindow.execScript "__doPostBack('TabAction', '2')"
```

Which I re-write to accept the EVENTARGUMENT as a constant, `OPTION_CHOSEN`, so different tabs can be retrieved by changing the its value at the top.

After executing the function a little time is left to refresh the page and then the table is grabbed by its `id`:

```
Set hTable = .document.getElementById("ctl00_ctl00_MainContent_Layout_1MainContent_gridResult")
```

Then the table is looped along its rows and columns (columns being the table cells along the length of each row).

---

**Examples from page:**

[image: Page]

---

Examples from code output:

[image: Example code output]

---

**Full code:**

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetTable()
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
    Const OPTION_CHOSEN As Long = 2             '0 Aperçu; 1 Court terme; 2 Long terme; 3 Portefeuille; 4 Frais & Détails

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "http://www.morningstar.fr/fr/fundquickrank/default.aspx"
        While .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        .document.parentWindow.execScript "__doPostBack('TabAction', ' " & OPTION_CHOSEN & "')"

        Do While .Busy = True Or .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

        Dim hTable As HTMLTable, tRow As HTMLTableRow, tCell As HTMLTableCell

        Set hTable = .document.getElementById("ctl00_ctl00_MainContent_Layout_1MainContent_gridResult")
        Dim c As Long, r As Long
        With ActiveSheet
            For Each tRow In hTable.Rows
                For Each tCell In tRow.Cells
                    c = c + 1: .Cells(r + 1, c) = tCell.innerText
                Next tCell
                c = 0: r = r + 1
            Next tRow
            .Columns("A:A").Delete
            .UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit
        End With
        .Quit
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

---

**References (VBE > Tools > References):**

1. Microsoft Internet Controls

Comment: hey, can you please look at my question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52618357/scrape-data-from-web-page-source-where-url-doesnt-change
i will add a bounty to it in once i'm able to, in 11 hours

Comment: will look in a few minutes

Comment: Hey, sorry, of course it did. Using this code for one of my automatons, modified a bit but this version worked as well. Huge thank you)

Comment: Hey, sorry, I got confused. This isnt my thread. I asked you to look at my thread in the comments and you helped me with mine. I did accept the answer there

Comment: I thought you did @lalachka :-)

Comment: I think Jerome disappeared early last year

Comment: Yeah lol. I went to accept, didnt see the checkmark to do so and got even more confused :)))))

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Get_Info()

Dim Elems, e As Variant

Const READYSTATE_COMPLETE& = 4&
Dim ie As Object
Set ie = Nothing
DoEvents

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
DoEvents

With ie
    .Visible = True
    .Navigate "http://www.morningstar.fr/fr/fundquickrank/default.aspx"
    While Not .readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        DoEvents
    Wend
End With

With ie.Document
    Set Elems = .getElementsByTagName("span")
    DoEvents
    For Each e In Elems
        If e.getAttribute("onclick") = "__doPostBack('TabAction', '2')" Then
            e.Click
            'try to insert your table export code here
            Exit For
        End If
    Next e

End With

Set Elems = Nothing
Set e = Nothing

'ie.Quit Quit Internet Explorer once the exporting is done
Set ie = Nothing

MsgBox "Done"
End Sub
```

The code above navigates directly to the tab you want. Try to combine it with your code to export the table and maybe it will work. ie.Visible=True just to make sure you navigate to the right URL, but make it false once you see it works. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you, it redirects me to the right page. However, I can't manage to "save" the redirection in order to export the data (in short, it's still the welcome page that is scraped). And I don't know how to update IE so that it keeps the last path in memory.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to get the tabular data from that target page using IE then this is one such way to achieve that.

```
Sub Fetch_Data()
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer, html As HTMLDocument
    Dim posts As Object, post As Object, elem As Object, trow As Object

    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "http://www.morningstar.fr/fr/fundquickrank/default.aspx"
        While .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        Set html = .document
    End With

    For Each post In html.getElementsByClassName("ms_tab_inactivetext")
        If InStr(post.innerText, "Long terme") > 0 Then post.ParentNode.Click: Exit For
    Next post

    Do While IE.Busy = True Or IE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

    Set posts = html.getElementById("ctl00_ctl00_MainContent_Layout_1MainContent_gridResult")

    For Each elem In posts.Rows
        For Each trow In elem.Cells
            c = c + 1: Cells(r + 1, c) = trow.innerText
        Next trow
        c = 0: r = r + 1
    Next elem
    IE.Quit
End Sub
```

Reference to add to the library:

```
1. Microsoft HTML Object Library
2. Microsoft Internet Controls
```