# scrape data from web page source where url doesn't change

Tags: ms-access, url, web-scraping, vba

I need to do the following

- Go to
  http://healthapps.state.nj.us/facilities/acSetSearch.aspx?by=county
- Select "**Special Hospital**" and "**All Ambulatory Care Facilities **NOTE #2**"
- Click **SEARCH**
- Loop through all the hospitals in the list
- Click on each hospital
- Get some data from the hospital page

I have 2 problems

1. I don't know how to select the "**Special Hospital**" and "**All Ambulatory Care Facilities **NOTE #2**"
2. When I manually select those 2 types and then click on some of the hospitals, the URL doesn't become selection specific. 
   It becomes http://healthapps.state.nj.us/facilities/acFacilityList.aspx after I select the 2 types, then stays that way when I click on the hospitals.
   Therefore, I'm not able to write the code that will scrape those pages because I don't know how to specify the URL for each hospital.

I apologize, this has to be a very basic question but I wasn't able to google anything useful on it for Access VBA

here's the code that pulls data from a page, i didn't do the loops yet, so this is just a basic pull of the source data behind a page

```
Public Function btnGetWebData_Click() 
    Dim strURL
    Dim HTML_Content As HTMLDocument
    Dim dados As Object

    'Create HTMLFile Object
    Set HTML_Content = New HTMLDocument

    'Get the WebPage Content to HTMLFile Object
    With CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp")
        .Open "GET", "http://healthapps.state.nj.us/facilities/acFacilityList.aspx", False
        'http://healthapps.state.nj.us/facilities/acFacilityList.aspx
        .Send
        HTML_Content.Body.innerHTML = .responseText
        Debug.Print .responseText
        Debug.Print HTML_Content.Body.innerHTML
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: Question: Would you be able and willing to use a different service? Rather than trying to scrape websites, another option might be the [CMS NPPES NPI registry](https://npiregistry.cms.hhs.gov/). You can search for providers by state and taxonomy (so, for example, you could look for special hospitals in NJ). They also provide a [free API](https://npiregistry.cms.hhs.gov/registry/help-api) that's pretty easy to use. Results are returned in JSON, so you'll have to parse that (I would recommend [this library](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON)).

Comment: lol interesting. i do work with that file, i'm afraid it doesn't have the data i'm looking for and i know how to parse it :) someone helped me write a piece in python. i will check if it has it, thank you for the idea!

Comment: nope, it doesn't have it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It navigates to each result page, and back to homepage in between so as to leverage the postBack links through clicks.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub VisitPages()
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "http://healthapps.state.nj.us/facilities/acSetSearch.aspx?by=county"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        With .document
            .querySelector("#middleContent_cbType_5").Click
            .querySelector("#middleContent_cbType_12").Click
            .querySelector("#middleContent_btnGetList").Click
        End With

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        Dim list As Object, i  As Long
        Set list = .document.querySelectorAll("#main_table [href*=doPostBack]")
        For i = 0 To list.Length - 1
            list.item(i).Click

            While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

            Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 3) '<== Delete me later. This is just to demo page changes
            'do stuff with new page
            .Navigate2 .document.URL             '<== back to homepage
            While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
            Set list = .document.querySelectorAll("#main_table [href*=doPostBack]") 'reset list (often required in these scenarios)
        Next
        Stop                                     '<== Delete me later
        '.Quit '<== Remember to quit application
    End With
End Sub
```

---

Same thing with executing the postBacks

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub VisitPages()
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "http://healthapps.state.nj.us/facilities/acSetSearch.aspx?by=county"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        With .document
            .querySelector("#middleContent_cbType_5").Click
            .querySelector("#middleContent_cbType_12").Click
            .querySelector("#middleContent_btnGetList").Click
        End With

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        Dim list As Object, i  As Long, col As Collection
        Set col = New Collection
        Set list = .document.querySelectorAll("#main_table [href*=doPostBack]")
        For i = 0 To list.Length - 1
           col.Add CStr(list.item(i))
        Next
        For i = 1 To col.Count
            .document.parentWindow.execScript col.item(i)
             While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
            'Do stuff with page
            .Navigate2 .document.URL
            While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        Next
        Stop                                     '<== Delete me later
        '.Quit '<== Remember to quit application
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: 2nd version works perfect!! 1st highlight this line .Document.parentWindow.execScript col.Item(i). 
It doesn't really matter, 2nd one seems to do what i need. do i accept the answer now or do i wait until i can do the bounty? thank you again!!!!

Comment: It's up to you. You can save yourself rep points by not offering a bounty. If you offer a bounty you may get better answers. You can always upvote if helpful. Accept if you wish. You have plenty of choices. The important thing is to get something you feel will deliver what you require reliably.

Comment: i'm happy with the answer, i just wanted to give up some points for it, this is a very useful thing!! one more dumb question, how do i get the source for the page your'e looping through? i'm playing around with my old code now, to plug it in, but figured i'd ask :)

Comment: The innerHTML should be .document.body.innerHTML  if that is what you mean?

Comment: yes!! you're amazing. so how do i give up the points now? once i can post the bounty, will it add points to you? i don't know this site that well

Comment: Bounties are designed to attract interest to questions that don't have an answer after a day or two I think. So, you don't really need to offer a bounty if you get an answer sooner than the point at which you can offer one.

Comment: got it, i was hoping i can add it to reward an answer. i really appreciate you doing this :)

Comment: Were you offered the possibility to put a bounty on? I thought it required a day or two.

Comment: no lol, i have to wait another 10 hours. otherwise i would've added it before i asked you for help :)

Comment: I thought so. The fact that you accepted is appreciated and that you are grateful is wonderful! I post a lot of web-scraping answers that OPs don't bother to accept even though they use.

Comment: sorry, can i ask for your help one more time? same project, having issues searching the source.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52673819/using-instr-to-search-for-quotes-spaces-colons-etc