# using InStr to search for quotes, spaces, colons, etc

Tags: ms-access, web-scraping, vba

this is a continuation of this question
[scrape data from web page source where url doesn't change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52618357/scrape-data-from-web-page-source-where-url-doesnt-change)

i'm now trying to search the scraped data and i'm not able to code it properly, it's not finding the text below

**`<span id="middleContent_lbName_county" style="font-weight:bold;">`**

i tried doing it like this

```
InStr(.Document.Body.innerHTML,"<span id=" & Chr(34) & "middleContent_lbName_county" & Chr(34) & " style=" & Chr(34) & "font-weight" & Chr(58) & "bold" & Chr(59) & "")
```

and i'm getting 0 in return.

this works

```
InStr(.Document.Body.innerHTML, "<span id=" & Chr(34) & "middleContent_lbName_county")
```

but it's not unique enough and i'm getting way too many results.

Comment: Are you after that html string? And is there an example URL to work with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a little unclear but there is an id there you can use and the string is the outerhtml of the element

```
.document.getElementById("middleContent_lbName_county").outerHTML
```

The info within is:

```
.document.getElementById("middleContent_lbName_county").innerText
```

Using this, `.innerText`,  will return the facility name.

With your former code:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub VisitPages()
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "http://healthapps.state.nj.us/facilities/acSetSearch.aspx?by=county"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        With .document
            .querySelector("#middleContent_cbType_5").Click
            .querySelector("#middleContent_cbType_12").Click
            .querySelector("#middleContent_btnGetList").Click
        End With

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        Dim list As Object, i  As Long
        Set list = .document.querySelectorAll("#main_table [href*=doPostBack]")
        For i = 0 To list.Length - 1
            list.item(i).Click

            While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

           ' Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 3) '<== Delete me later. This is just to demo page changes
                Debug.Print .document.getElementById("middleContent_lbName_county").outerHTML
            'do stuff with new page
            .Navigate2 .document.URL             '<== back to homepage
            While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
            Set list = .document.querySelectorAll("#main_table [href*=doPostBack]") 'reset list (often required in these scenarios)
        Next
        Stop                                     '<== Delete me later
        '.Quit '<== Remember to quit application
    End With
End Sub
```

---

Some sample results:

[image]

Comment: you're amazing :))) i'm going to edit my original for the rest of the stuff i'm trying to scrape, i'm able to get it, but i have a feeling there's a much easier way than what i'm about to do (do a loop that will search the text around it, i'm sure i will get a ton of junk)

Comment: No worries. Pleased to have helped.

Comment: look at the original post, i added some more questions :) those aren't that important, i have a way of doing them but if you don't mind, you'r way is so much cleaner

Comment: Hi, You shouldn't edit old questions with new requirements as you may invalidate the given answers if there are answers given. If no answers, no problem. Instead you should ask new question(s). You can certainly link to that question

Comment: got it, will post a new one and delete the edit, sorry)

Comment: No worries. Let me know when posted. Also, I hang out in [dawghaus](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169987/dawgs-waffle-haus) where you can stop by and ping me with @qharr if you have additional quick queries.

Comment: should i ask there instead and delete this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52674206/scrape-data-from-a-table-on-a-website-without-having-to-search-for-tags. it told me my title is bad and i will get downvotes :) i don't know how to decribe it any better