# scrape data from a table on a website without having to search for tags

Tags: ms-access, web-scraping, vba

this is a continuation from this question
[using InStr to search for quotes, spaces, colons, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52673819/using-instr-to-search-for-quotes-spaces-colons-etc)

i'm also trying to get all this data below. i was going to do a loop that will search for `<td align="left">`
but i have a feeling it will bring in a ton of garbage along with the results i need. i'm wondering if there's a better way of doing this.

```
<b>Total Hospital Beds</b></td> 
                                        <td align="left">Adult ICU (intensive care unit) CCU (critical care unit)</td>
                                        <td align="left">26</td>
                                        <td align="left">Medical/surgical</td>
                                        <td align="left">198</td>
                                        <td align="left">Pediatric</td>
                                        <td align="left">20</td>

                                        <td align="center" colspan="2"><b>Services</b></td>
                                        <td align="left">Acute Hemodialoysis Service</td>
                                        <td align="left">Chronic Hemodialysis Stations</td>
                                        <td align="left">Magnetic Resonance Imaging - On Site</td>
                                        <td align="left">Mixed OR's</td>
                                        <td align="left">7</td>
```

basically, everything at the section on the bottom, screenshot attached
[image]

This is what I have but now it stops after the first page, the bolded line is highlighted

```
Public Sub VisitPages()
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "http://healthapps.state.nj.us/facilities/acSetSearch.aspx?by=county"

        While .Busy Or .ReadyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        With .Document
            .querySelector("#middleContent_cbType_1").Click
            .querySelector("#middleContent_cbType_4").Click
            .querySelector("#middleContent_btnGetList").Click
        End With

        While .Busy Or .ReadyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        Dim list As Object, i  As Long
        Set list = .Document.querySelectorAll("#main_table [href*=doPostBack]")

        For i = 0 To list.Length - 1

            list.Item(i).Click

            While .Busy Or .ReadyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

            ' Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 3) '<== Delete me later. This is just to demo page changes
            **Debug.Print .Document.getElementById("middleContent_lbName_county").outerHTML**
            'do stuff with new page

            Dim FirstOcc As Long
            Dim TtlHosp As Variant
            Dim FLine As Variant
            Dim FLineFixed As Variant

            TtlHosp = Mid(.Document.Body.innerHTML, InStr(.Document.Body.innerHTML, "Total Hospital Beds"), 4000)

            Do Until InStr(TtlHosp, "<td align=" & Chr(34) & "left" & Chr(34) & ">") = 0

                FirstOcc = InStr(TtlHosp, "<td align=" & Chr(34) & "left" & Chr(34) & ">")
                FLine = Mid(TtlHosp, FirstOcc + 17, 150)
                FLineFixed = Mid(FLine, 1, InStr(FLine, "</td>") - 1)
                Debug.Print FLineFixed
                TtlHosp = Mid(TtlHosp, FirstOcc + 17, 2000)

            Loop

            .Navigate2 .Document.URL             '<== back to homepage
            While .Busy Or .ReadyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
            Set list = .Document.querySelectorAll("#main_table [href*=doPostBack]") 'reset list (often required in these scenarios)
        Next
        Stop                                     '<== Delete me later
        '.Quit '<== Remember to quit application
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You want to grab the appropriate table and loop it to get those values. It is hard with the above to know which URLs are involved, if the table is present on each result, do you want for each result where present? etc...

Comment: This looks so ugly. Import a CSV, don't do this.

Comment: Import a csv how? And I dont see anything ugly about it, it worked for what I needed. But I'd be interested in other ways of getting it done

Comment: @MisterGeeky Do you have a csv in mind? This is specific info that comes from links that you can't just input as they are dynamically generated server side. Use of CSS selectors is recommeded as most modern browsers are highly optimized for CSS work.

Comment: @MisterGeeky Do you have a csv in mind? This is specific info that is dynamically generated in response to actions performed on the page. Use of CSS selectors is recommeded as most modern browsers are highly optimized for CSS work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that info is only for special hospital selection and that the bed info is in the third table. (Note: Results are currently written in Excel)

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub VisitPages()
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer, ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "http://healthapps.state.nj.us/facilities/acSetSearch.aspx?by=county"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        With .document
            .querySelector("#middleContent_cbType_5").Click
            .querySelector("#middleContent_btnGetList").Click
        End With

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        Dim list As Object, i  As Long
        Set list = .document.querySelectorAll("#main_table [href*=doPostBack]")
        For i = 0 To list.Length - 1
            list.item(i).Click

            While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

            WriteTable .document.getElementsByTagName("table")(3), .document.getElementById("middleContent_lbName_county").innerText, GetLastRow(ws, 3) + 1, ws
            'do stuff with new page
            .Navigate2 .document.URL             '<== back to homepage
            While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
            Set list = .document.querySelectorAll("#main_table [href*=doPostBack]") 'reset list (often required in these scenarios)
        Next
        .Quit                                    '<== Remember to quit application
    End With
End Sub

Public Function GetLastRow(ByVal ws As Worksheet, Optional ByVal columnNumber As Long = 1) As Long
    With ws
        GetLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, columnNumber).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
End Function

Public Sub WriteTable(ByVal hTable As HTMLTable, facility As String, Optional ByVal startRow As Long = 1, Optional ByVal ws As Worksheet)
    If ws Is Nothing Then Set ws = ActiveSheet

    Dim tRow As Object, tCell As Object, tr As Object, td As Object, r As Long, c As Long, titleRow As Long
    r = startRow: titleRow = startRow
    With ws
        Set tRow = hTable.getElementsByTagName("tr")
        .Cells(titleRow, 1) = facility
        For Each tr In tRow
            r = r + 1
            Set tCell = tr.getElementsByTagName("td")
            c = 2
            For Each td In tCell
                .Cells(r, c).Value = td.innerText
                c = c + 1
            Next td
        Next tr
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: you are amazing!!! this is for excel but it doesn't matter,  it does what i need. my job should hire you instead :)))))

Comment: Sorry. Forgot about the access tag!

Comment: who cares))) it would have to go to excel anyway. thank you!!! i wish i can code like this

Comment: The simple answer is “you can”. Just requires a little study and practice. I can always recommend resources to help.

Comment: Start with these https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLNIs-AWhQzcl3xKvF8sVL4sWRWICj_clM and let me know when you want more.

Comment: hey, I have another question with bounty. Can you please help or point me somewhere where I can learn to do it? Thank you! https://stackoverflow.com/q/58332598/453116