# access vba IE getElementById "object required" error 424

Tags: vba, ms-access, getelementbyid

this is related to this question

[scrape data from a table on a website without having to search for tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52674206/scrape-data-from-a-table-on-a-website-without-having-to-search-for-tags)

this code worked up until a few days ago, the only change since then was changing to Windows 10 but that shouldn't affect it, should it?

also, it seems that it scrapes the first record and then gives the error. however, if i click DEBUG, then STEP OUT, it works and goes to the next record and i again have to click DEBUG, STEP OUT and so on. 81 times.

There are other functions being called from it, they just scrape more stuff and put it in a table, i don't think they're the issue, but i can add them if needed.

The line that gives the error 424 is

```
If .Document.getElementById("middleContent_lbType").outerHTML Like "*General Acute Care Hospital*" Then
```

here's the code

```
Public Sub VisitPages()

DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE FROM ScrapedFacs"

    AutoID = 1
    Dim ie As New InternetExplorer
    'Set ie = New InternetExplorerMedium
    With ie
        .Visible = False
        .navigate "http://healthapps.state.nj.us/facilities/acSetSearch.aspx?by=county"

        While .Busy Or .ReadyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        With .Document
            .querySelector("#middleContent_cbType_1").Click
            .querySelector("#middleContent_cbType_4").Click
            .querySelector("#middleContent_btnGetList").Click
        End With

        While .Busy Or .ReadyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        Dim list As Object, i  As Long
        Set list = .Document.querySelectorAll("#main_table [href*=doPostBack]")
        For i = 0 To list.Length - 1
            list.Item(i).Click

            While .Busy Or .ReadyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

If .Document.getElementById("middleContent_lbType").outerHTML Like "*General Acute Care Hospital*" Then
FacType = "General Acute Care Hospital"
ElseIf .Document.getElementById("middleContent_lbType").outerHTML Like "*Psychiatric Hospital*" Then
FacType = "Psychiatric Hospital"
End If


Address = Replace(Replace(Replace(.Document.getElementById("middleContent_lbAddress").outerHTML, "<span id=" & Chr(34) & "middleContent_lbAddress" & Chr(34) & ">", ""), "<br>", ", "), "</span>", "")

            WriteTable .Document.getElementsByTagName("table")(3), .Document.getElementById("middleContent_lbName_county").innerText


            'do stuff with new page
            .Navigate2 .Document.URL             '<== back to homepage
            While .Busy Or .ReadyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
            Set list = .Document.querySelectorAll("#main_table [href*=doPostBack]") 'reset list (often required in these scenarios)

        Next
       ' Stop                                     '<== Delete me later
        .Quit '<== Remember to quit application
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because of running code too fast

So either add a sleep before the line

```
Sleep 1
...Document.getElementById("middleContent_lbType")..
```

Or start checking if there is a return value or not

```
Set obj = .Document.getElementById("middleContent_lbType")
If obj is Nothing:
   Sleep 1
   Set obj = .Document.getElementById("middleContent_lbType")
End If

If obj.outerHTML Like "*General Acute Care Hospital*" Then
...
```

Comment: Thank you!! Will check today. Any idea why it worked before?

Comment: Probably speed was fine earlier now its slow and may be its just a few ms that may make a difference in such cases

Comment: Omg I'm so sorry, I thought bounty was added the minute I accepted the answer. Actually, I'm still not sure if I awarded it, the icon looks the same. Did I?

Comment: Usually accepted answer gets the bounty automatically at the end of the bounty period. It seems you removed the answer as accepted one just now

Comment: Lol sorry, I'm doing this from my phone, must have touched it by accident