# loop through page numbers when href contians doPostBack() in webpage

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I need to scrape date on ever page by clicking page number present in the webpage below.

I have mentioned sample website which looks similar to my html webpage.

Sample web page is this [Webpage](https://www.mfa.gov.tr/sub.ar.mfa?dcabec54-44b3-4aaa-a725-70d0caa8a0ae).

Code i have is below:

```
Sub Test()
Dim IE As Object
Dim i As Long, strText As String
Dim y As Long, z As Long, wb As Excel.Workbook, ws As Excel.Worksheet
Dim myBtn As Object
Dim Table As Object, tbody As Object, datarow As Object, thlist As Object, trlist As Object

Set wb = Excel.ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = wb.ActiveSheet
Sheets("Data").Select

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
my_url = webpage.com
With IE
    .Visible = True
    .navigate my_url
    Do Until Not IE.Busy And IE.readyState = 4
        DoEvents
    Loop
End With
Set doc = IE.document
y = 1
z = 1
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:02")
Set tbody = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("table")(0).getElementsByTagName("tbody")(0)
Set thlist = tbody.getElementsByTagName("tr")(0).getElementsByTagName("th")
Dim ii As Integer
For ii = 0 To thlist.Length - 1
    ws.Cells(z, y).Value = thlist(ii).innerText
    y = y + 1
Next ii
Set datarow = tbody.getElementsByTagName("tr")
y = 1
z = 2
Dim jj As Integer
Dim datarowtdlist As Object
For jj = 1 To datarow.Length - 4
    Set datarowtdlist = datarow(jj).getElementsByTagName("td")
    Dim hh As Integer, x As Integer
    x = y
    For hh = 0 To datarowtdlist.Length - 1
        ws.Cells(z, x).Value = datarowtdlist(hh).innerText
        x = x + 1
    Next hh
    z = z + 1
Next jj
Set IE = Nothing
End Sub
```

Im happy to help if my question is not clear.

Thanks for the support.

Comment: @QHarr, nothing we have to enter. Just enter website and extract table..

Comment: Need to extract content in the table according to page numbers. (page numbers are located at bottom of the screen right side). No need to enter any search criteria.

Comment: `ie.document.parentwindow.execScript "javascript:__doPostBack('sb$grd','Page$10');"` ?

Comment: QHarr, where should I include this line in the code above and how will this click the page numbers until the last page.

Comment: Could you please update the code for me to understand..

Comment: I haven't looked at what you have, but it looks like you'd insert that bit right where you want to change the page.

Comment: Try it first with Page$2 then left me know if works. You want it as @wazz says, when you want to change page. If that works, I will write up an answer to determine and loop all pages.

Comment: QHarr, yes that line worked fine for me, "that line clicked on page10" on that webpage. I don't have idea on how to loop that for every page until last page. Could you please help me on that.

Comment: QHarr, in the sample site which i mentioned there are only 10 pages, whereas in my original site there are more than 100 pages that might get change in future also so I need to loop till the last page number.

Comment: QHarr, is my question clear for you.. do I need to provide any more information..

Comment: No. But as you didn't write @qharr I didn't get notified of your messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The next page is retrieved by incrementing the  `__EVENTARGUMENT` of the `__doPostBack` e.g. from 1 to 2, 2 to 3 etc, and then triggering the `__doPostBack` with the new value. The last page will have been reached when the final `td` node (in the pagination area) no longer has a child `href`  containing the `__EVENTTARGET` (sb$grd). Using this logic you can loop, incrementing, and have an exit condition, as shown below.

For more info about this function with ASP.NET see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50911208/6241235).

```
Public Sub LoopPages()

    Dim ie As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

    Set ie = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

    With ie

        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "https://www.mfa.gov.tr/sub.ar.mfa?dcabec54-44b3-4aaa-a725-70d0caa8a0ae"
        
        While .Busy Or .readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Wend
        
        Dim i As Long

        i = 1

        Do
        
            Debug.Print i
            Debug.Print .document.querySelector(".sub_lstitm").innerText
        
            If .document.querySelectorAll("tr:nth-child(1) td:last-child [href*='sb$grd']").length = 0 Then Exit Do
        
            .document.parentWindow.execScript "__doPostBack('sb$grd','Page$" & i + 1 & "');"
        
            While .Busy Or .readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Wend
        
            'do something with new page
        
            i = i + 1
        
        Loop
  
        Stop                                     'stops at 185
        .Quit
    End With

End Sub
```